# How is a blank, new Cocoa app project linking with the system frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've created a blank new Cocoa Application project. Inside it has just

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

in `main.m` and `AppDelegate.h` (plus the necessary boilerplate). The "**Link Binary with Libraries**" list is **empty** under Build Phases, as is the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" list under General.

Yet, the **app links and runs** just **fine**. I wonder **why**?

The reason I'm asking is because in a different project, similarly not explicitly linked to any system frameworks, and with the necessary `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` the compilation succeeds, but linking fails unless I link with the Cocoa framework. Would like to know the exact reason.

---

Here's the Link step from the blank new project that mysteriously works:

```
Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Products/Debug/Dummy.app/Contents/MacOS/Dummy normal x86_64
    cd /Users/me/Desktop/Dummy
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch x86_64
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
-L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Products/Debug
-F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Products/Debug
-filelist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Intermediates/Dummy.build/Debug/Dummy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Dummy.LinkFileList
-Xlinker
-rpath
-Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks
-mmacosx-version-min=10.11
-Xlinker
-object_path_lto
-Xlinker /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Intermediates/Dummy.build/Debug/Dummy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Dummy_lto.o
-Xlinker
-export_dynamic
-Xlinker
-no_deduplicate
-fobjc-arc
-fobjc-link-runtime
-Xlinker
-dependency_info
-Xlinker /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Intermediates/Dummy.build/Debug/Dummy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Dummy_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-denigwgxslheroapywoedahwvhkx/Build/Products/Debug/Dummy.app/Contents/MacOS/Dummy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new project, Xcode will set the `Link Frameworks Automatically` flag to YES. Then the clang linking flag will be set to `CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK = YES`. With this option, clang will linking the framework for you automatically.

When you set this flag to `NO` 
[image]

Then the linking process will be failed without adding the library into `Link Binary with Libraries` list.

Comment: Interesting, but `Link Frameworks Automatically` is set to YES (the default) in the other project. Setting it to NO does make the dummy project's linking to fail though, but it seems like there are some other settings at play.

Comment: P.S. All other settings between the dummy project and the other project are pretty much identical; perhaps it's an Xcode bug.

Comment: Maybe. There is an [article](http://indiestack.com/2015/02/enable-clang-modules-disable-auto-linking/) about this flag and modules. You can learn more about auto linking if you like.

Comment: This setting doesn't seem to work with `AVKit` framework. If I don't add it explicitly to the target's Frameworks list, when running the app an error is logged in the Console app and any `AVPlayerView` is not shown.